# How to resolve this issue digital envelope routines?

Tags: angular-cli-v8

How to resolve this issue digital envelope routines?

My Angular version is 16.2.0.

Node version: v18.13.0

When I run an Angular project, it shows the below error. How do I resolve it?

error:

```
{
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```